# Image magick convert pdf to tiff file

Tags: image, imagemagick

Having problem with image magick cant convert chinese name from textfield of pdf.

Is there anyone know how to deal with this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  To increase the chances of getting help, please share some code samples.

Comment: Please share a sample file.

Comment: Likely the font isn't imbedded in the PDF and is not in the ghostscript-accessible set of fonts on your computer (Imagemagick uses ghostscript rather than the system fonts; so make sure you've got the appropriate font loaded in ghostscript).

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson so the font embedded in the PDF mus be the same set of fonts in the ghoscript?

Comment: If it's embedded, then no -- I think ghostscript can access the embedded font. It it's not embedded, then ghostscript needs another way to access it.